# Changing alignment inside a ContentControl with Office.js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I have the following code:

```
Word.run(context => {
  var range = context.document.getSelection();
  var cc = range.insertContentControl();
  var ccRange = cc.insertHtml(myContent, 'replace');
  // ...
```

It works fine. If I have the document alignment set to, for instance, `Justified`, the content inside the new ContentControl will be `Justified`, too. I know users can simply select the content and change the aligment, but I need to set it to `Left` by default.

I know how to handle the font to make sure it follows the same styling as the document and for that I have this code that immediately follows the code above:

```
  // ...
  context.load(range, 'font');
  context.load(ccRange, 'font');

  context.sync().then(() => {
    ccRange.font.color = range.font.color;
    ccRange.font.highlightColor = range.font.highlightColor;
    ccRange.font.name = range.font.name;
    ccRange.font.size = range.font.size;
    // ...
```

Based on this example, I suppose there is a similar way I can change the alignment inside the ContentControl, but so far I have failed.

If I understood correctly, the ContentControl has a `paragraphs` property and a single paragraph has an `alignment` property so I'm guessing that's what I need, but my few attempts at accessing it yielded no results (such as `context.load(cc, 'paragraphs');` and then accessing the property after context syncing).

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it a little easier to "load" the variable rather than the context but either way works.

You load `'paragraphs'` just like you do with `'font'`. You can also load them at the same time using `'paragraphs, font'` to make things even simpler.

For example, this code will insert a `ContentControl`, insert some HTML content and set the `alignment` to `'centered'`:

```
return Word.run(function (context) {
    let range = context.document.getSelection();
    let cc = range.insertContentControl();
    let ccRange = cc.insertHtml('<b>Hello World</b>', 'Replace');

    ccRange.load('font, paragraphs');
    return context.sync().then(() => {
        ccRange.paragraphs.items[0].alignment = 'Centered';
        return context.sync();
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for me, thanks. I was missing the `items` part. I was trying, among other things, like this: `.paragraphs[0]` and `.paragraphs.m_items[0]` (a prop I saw in the log, but it did look like an internal prop).